# PowerShell Script execution hangs in Windows Server 2012R2

Tags: windows, powershell, process, windows-server-2012-r2, freeze

One of my script hangs during one of our product installation. Hangs is happening while executing some of the common PowerShell and native ExEs from PowerShell.

more details in below question which is actually logged in [Windows PowerShell Forums](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/c7f4e0e5-7243-4200-8921-88dbbce7d226/reporting-the-questiong-form-windowsserver-general-forums?forum=winserverpowershell).

we use msdeploy,iisreset,appcmd here during web packages installation, this is the place where it hangs, but hang happens after successful execution of msdeploy.exe. I tried using latest available version of msdeploy, is still hangs some times.

We have around 7 web packages, hang happens after deploying a package as well as before deploying a package.

Code logic here.

Step 1: Test msdeploy exists, if not install it

Step 2 : iisreset (hangs here sometimes)

Step 3 : check if the app pool is available, if so `Stop-WebAppPool` (hangs here sometimes)

Step 4: install web package using msdeploy

Step 5: get the app pool state and start if it is not started – (some times hangs here)

Step 6: do some app pool settings using appcmd.exe (hangs some times after this execution)

Step 7: some other app pool settings like `Set-ItemProperty IIS:\AppPools\$appPoolName -Name recycling.periodicRestart.memory -Value $appPoolRestartMemory`

Step 8 : get the next package and go to Step 1

Sometimes, hang happens after executing
 `netsh http delete urlacl url=$url`

Note: None of the hangs are consistent, each and every time, hang happens in either one place.

I did procdump analysis of the powershell process and ended up in ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjectsroutine for all hangs.

same is being shown by the proc explorer threads view as well.

PFB the hanging handle's stack

```
 ntdll.dll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects+0xa
 KERNELBASE.dll!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0xed
 clr.dll!GetMetaDataPublicInterfaceFromInternal+0x3a95e
 clr.dll!GetMetaDataPublicInterfaceFromInternal+0x3a7f8
 clr.dll!GetMetaDataPublicInterfaceFromInternal+0x3a5f1
 clr.dll!GetMetaDataPublicInterfaceFromInternal+0x3eeb5
 [Managed to Unmanaged Transition]
 mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.WaitHandle.InternalWaitOne+0x21
 mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOne+0x31
 System.Management.Automation.dll!    
 System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PipelineBase.Invoke+0x34
 Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost.dll!    
 Microsoft.PowerShell.Executor.ExecuteCommandHelper+0x154
 Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost.dll!    
 Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost.DoRunspaceInitialization+0x7ed
 Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost.dll!    
 Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost.DoCreateRunspace+0x1d3
 Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost.dll!    
 Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost.CreateRunspace+0x49
 Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost.dll!    
 Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost.DoRunspaceLoop+0xc3
 Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost.dll!    
 Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost.Run+0x14c
 Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost.dll!    
 Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost.Start+0x1aa
 Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost.dll!                            
 Microsoft.PowerShell.UnmanagedPSEntry.Start+0x33c
 [Unmanaged to Managed Transition]
 clr.dll!DllCanUnloadNowInternal+0xbe3
 clr.dll!DllCanUnloadNowInternal+0xaa3
 clr.dll!GetMetaDataInternalInterfaceFromPublic+0x1abde
 clr.dll!GetMetaDataInternalInterfaceFromPublic+0x1aa87
 [Managed to Unmanaged Transition]
 mscorlib.dll!System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal+0x80
 mscorlib.dll!System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke+0x92
 [Unmanaged to Managed Transition]
 clr.dll!DllCanUnloadNowInternal+0xbe3
 clr.dll!DllCanUnloadNowInternal+0xaa3
 clr.dll!DllCanUnloadNowInternal+0x12f5
 clr.dll!SetRuntimeInfo+0x20b4
 clr.dll!SetRuntimeInfo+0x1c16
 clr.dll!SetRuntimeInfo+0x253d
 clr.dll!SetRuntimeInfo+0x2906
 clr.dll!SetRuntimeInfo+0x276d
 clr.dll!SetRuntimeInfo+0x26ae
 powershell.exe+0x8663
 powershell.exe+0x7c67
 powershell.exe+0xa6cc
 KERNEL32.DLL!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x22
 ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x34
```